# Timer auto restart after method finished

Tags: c#, timer

I set a timer logic in Main program to AutorReset every 30 seconds, so my LogCollection method (which extract data) will loop every 30 seconds and my code can keep going on.

The problem is that I realized that sometimes the time given is shorter than the method execution time which cause multiple method calls at the same time which results multiple data flood.

Q: How can I make the timer wait and no to do another cycle before the method finished?

Timer code looks like:

```
        Timer thetimer = new Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30).TotalMilliseconds);
        thetimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(LogCollector.LogCollection);
        thetimer.AutoReset = true;
        thetimer.Start();
```

I was thinking to add some While loop but than my code would loop on that forever and the rest of the code would not complete.
Please advise

Comment: There's a number of classes called `Timer` in .NET - which specific one are you using?

Comment: `using System.Timers;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would abandon `Timer` and use `async` instead:

```
while (true)
{
    var start = DateTime.Now;
    LogCollector.LogCollection();
    var timeRemaining = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30) - (DateTime.Now - start);
    await Task.Delay(Math.Max(timeRemaining.TotalMilliseconds, 0));
}
```

`Math.Max` is used in case the execution of `LogCollection()` exceeds 30 seconds, in which case `timeRemaining` would be negative.

If you have code to run after the loop, move it into a cancellable method:

```
async Task LogCollectionLoopAsync(TimeSpan minLoopTime, CancellationToken ct)
{
    while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        var start = DateTime.Now;
        LogCollector.LogCollection();
        var timeRemaining = minLoopTime - (DateTime.Now - start);
        await Task.Delay(Math.Max(timeRemaining.TotalMilliseconds, 0), ct);
    }
}
```

Then your `Main` method could be written like this:

```
async Task Main()
{
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

    var logCollectionTask = LogCollectionLoopAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), cts.Token);

    // Do your other stuff

    cts.Cancel();

    try { await logCollectionTask;  } catch { } // Cancellation causes an exception
}
```

Comment: sorry I'm not sure why in the last section (`Main`) you cancel with `cts.Cancel();` before you use `try{ }` .

Comment: @DanielA It cancels the delay; without that, the loop would continue forever and the `Task` would never complete.

Comment: but if I put the cancel there it might cancel the task before it's actually completed.  I need to be sure that `LogCollection()` finished before I can cancel.

Comment: It will. The `CancellationToken` will only cancel the delay, or the next iteration, not `LogCollection`. Notice how the token is passed to `Task.Delay`; cancelling that token will cause `Task.Delay` to throw an exception, completing the `Task` returned from `LogCollectionLoopAsync`.